# How to automatic change the selected item of an option tag when on click

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

i want to change the selected item using option tag dynamically. The following values inside in the dropdown button are the links from another page. But the result, when i select a value in the dropdown button, the value of option tag is not changing.

Here is my code:

```
<select name="select_item" class="select_item" id="menu1" onchange="function();">
                            <option value="<?= base_url('index/products'); ?>">Default sorting</option>
                            <option value="<?= base_url('index/prod_sort1'); ?>">Sort by A to Z</option>

                        </select>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu1' );
                            urlmenu.onchange = function() {
                            window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value,"_self" );
                            };
                            </script>
```

Comment: That is way jQuery is so great. it makes things like this very easy `$("#your_select_id").val("your_option_value")` .

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
       var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu1' );
       urlmenu.onchange = function() {
       window.location.href = urlmenu.options[urlmenu.selectedIndex].value;
       }  
 </script>
```